# Print several plots to PDF (one plot per page) in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib

From [matplotlib's](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/misc/multipage_pdf.html) documentation, this should allow me to print several plots to a PDF file, with one plot per page.

```
import datetime
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf import PdfPages
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Create the PdfPages object to which we will save the pages:
# The with statement makes sure that the PdfPages object is closed properly at
# the end of the block, even if an Exception occurs.
with PdfPages('multipage_pdf.pdf') as pdf:
    plt.figure(figsize=(3, 3))
    plt.plot(range(7), [3, 1, 4, 1, 5, 9, 2], 'r-o')
    plt.title('Page One')
    pdf.savefig()  # saves the current figure into a pdf page
    plt.close()

    # if LaTeX is not installed or error caught, change to `usetex=False`
    plt.rc('text', usetex=True)
    plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6))
    x = np.arange(0, 5, 0.1)
    plt.plot(x, np.sin(x), 'b-')
    plt.title('Page Two')
    pdf.attach_note("plot of sin(x)")  # you can add a pdf note to
                                       # attach metadata to a page
    pdf.savefig()
    plt.close()
```

However, when I run it, I get several `FileNotFoundErrors`, like this: `FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified`.

What am I doing wrong?

I have tried setting `usetex=False`, and that doesn't fix it.

The full error would be several pages long, and I'm not sure what's the best way to share it, but here's how it starts:

[image]

Comment: Please provide the entire error message.

Comment: You code works on my machine (Arch Linux). I get two plots. This means it's related your Windows setup. I suggest you try using a fully-qualified filename for the pdf - e.g. 'C:\Users\<username>\Documents\multipage_pdf.pdf'.

Comment: Working too on macOs.